# UIImagePickerController iPad problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[imagePicker release];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0) 
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                       animated:YES];
```

But this only destroys the `self.view` and does not show anything at all. When I set the inView: to `[self.view window]` the picker at least shows up. But it still removes the self.view. What do I have to do that the view doesn't disappear?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are initializing the UIImagePickerController wrong. Try changing it to

```
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to show a popup inside a view with that view itself!

initWithRootViewController is the view(controller) to show inside the popup.

inview is the view where the popup will pop up